# Color of the node of tree with graphviz using class_names

Tags: python-3.x, scikit-learn, decision-tree, graph-visualization, pydot

Expanding on a prior question:
[Changing colors for decision tree plot created using export graphviz](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42891148/changing-colors-for-decision-tree-plot-created-using-export-graphviz)

How would I color the nodes of the tree bases on the dominant class (species of iris), instead of a binary distinction? This should require a combination of the iris.target_names, the string describing the class, and iris.target, the class.

```
import pydotplus
from sklearn.datasets import load_iris
from sklearn import tree
import collections

clf = tree.DecisionTreeClassifier(random_state=42)
iris = load_iris()

clf = clf.fit(iris.data, iris.target)

dot_data = tree.export_graphviz(clf, out_file=None,
                                feature_names=iris.feature_names,
                                class_names=iris.target_names,
                                filled=True, rounded=True,
                                special_characters=True)
graph = pydotplus.graph_from_dot_data(dot_data)
nodes = graph.get_node_list()
edges = graph.get_edge_list()

colors = ('brown', 'forestgreen')
edges = collections.defaultdict(list)

for edge in graph.get_edge_list():
    edges[edge.get_source()].append(int(edge.get_destination()))

for edge in edges:
    edges[edge].sort()    
    for i in range(2):
        dest = graph.get_node(str(edges[edge][i]))[0]
        dest.set_fillcolor(colors[i])

graph.write_png('tree.png')
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The code from the example looks so familiar and is therefore easy to modify :)

For each node `Graphviz` tells us how many samples from each group we have, i.e. if it is a mixed population or the tree came to a decision. We can extract this info and use to get a color.

```
values = [int(ii) for ii in node.get_label().split('value = [')[1].split(']')[0].split(',')]
```

Alternatively you can map the `GraphViz` nodes back to the `sklearn` nodes:

```
values = clf.tree_.value[int(node.get_name())][0]
```

We only have 3 classes, so each one gets its own color (red, green, blue), mixed populations get mixed colors according to their distribution.

```
values = [int(255 * v / sum(values)) for v in values]
color = '#{:02x}{:02x}{:02x}'.format(values[0], values[1], values[2])
```

[image]

We can now see the separation nicely, the greener it gets the more of the 2nd class we have, same for blue and the 3rd class.

---

```
import pydotplus
from sklearn.datasets import load_iris
from sklearn import tree

clf = tree.DecisionTreeClassifier(random_state=42)
iris = load_iris()

clf = clf.fit(iris.data, iris.target)

dot_data = tree.export_graphviz(clf,
                                feature_names=iris.feature_names,
                                out_file=None,
                                filled=True,
                                rounded=True,
                                special_characters=True)
graph = pydotplus.graph_from_dot_data(dot_data)
nodes = graph.get_node_list()

for node in nodes:
    if node.get_label():
        values = [int(ii) for ii in node.get_label().split('value = [')[1].split(']')[0].split(',')]
        values = [int(255 * v / sum(values)) for v in values]
        color = '#{:02x}{:02x}{:02x}'.format(values[0], values[1], values[2])
        node.set_fillcolor(color)

graph.write_png('colored_tree.png')
```

---

A general solution for more than 3 classes which colors only the final nodes .

```
colors =  ('lightblue', 'lightyellow', 'forestgreen', 'lightred', 'white')

for node in nodes:
    if node.get_name() not in ('node', 'edge'):
        values = clf.tree_.value[int(node.get_name())][0]
        #color only nodes where only one class is present
        if max(values) == sum(values):    
            node.set_fillcolor(colors[numpy.argmax(values)])
        #mixed nodes get the default color
        else:
            node.set_fillcolor(colors[-1])
```

[image]

Comment: My personal problem has four classes. How would you generalize this for n classes?

Comment: I had intended to use: colors = ('lightblue', 'lightyellow', 'lightgreen', 'lightred',) and then interpolate between them.

Comment: @MyopicVisage: That's challenging :) Personally I would prefer to have only the final nodes colored, otherwise it becomes a christmas tree. I'll think about it a bit more.

Comment: I agree. My problem statement was intended to be read, color the node with the dominate class, so no interpolation is necessary.

Comment: @MyopicVisage: see updated answer for a general solution

Answer (score 1):

Great answers guys. Just to add to @Maximilian Peters's answer. One other thing that one can do identify leaf nodes for specific coloration is to check on the split_criteria(threshold) values. Since leaf nodes don't have child nodes, hence the absence of split criteria as well.

```
https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/a24c8b464d094d2c468a16ea9f8bf8d42d949f84/sklearn/tree/_tree.pyx
TREE_UNDEFINED = -2 
thresholds = clf.tree_.threshold
for node in nodes:
    if node.get_name() not in ('node', 'edge'):
        value = clf.tree_.value[int(node.get_name())][0]
        # color only nodes where only one class is present or if it is a leaf 
        # node
        if max(values) == sum(values) or 
            thresholds[int(node.get_name())] == TREE_UNDEFINED:    
                node.set_fillcolor(colors[numpy.argmax(value)])
        # mixed nodes get the default color
        else:
            node.set_fillcolor(colors[-1])
```

Not completely related to the question, but adding some more info in-case it is helpful to others.
Continuing on this idea of understanding the decision stumps of a tree-based classifier, Skater has added support to summarize all forms of tree-based models using tree surrogates. Check out the examples here.

https://github.com/datascienceinc/Skater/blob/master/examples/rule_list_notebooks/explanation_using_tree_surrogate.ipynb