# How to change colors for decision tree plot using sklearn plot_tree?

Tags: python, matplotlib, scikit-learn

How to change colors in decision tree plot using sklearn.tree.plot_tree **without** using graphviz as in this question: [Changing colors for decision tree plot created using export graphviz](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42891148/changing-colors-for-decision-tree-plot-created-using-export-graphviz)?

```
plt.figure(figsize=[21, 6])
ax1 = plt.subplot(121)
ax2 = plt.subplot(122)

ax1.plot(X[:, 0][y == 0], X[:, 1][y == 0], "bo")
ax1.plot(X[:, 0][y == 1], X[:, 1][y == 1], "g^")
ax1.contourf(xx, yy, pred.reshape(xx.shape), cmap=matplotlib.colors.ListedColormap(['b', 'g']), alpha=0.25)
ax1.set_title(title)

plot_tree(tree_clf, feature_names=["X", "y"], class_names=["blue", "green"], filled=True, rounded=True)
```

[image]

Comment: Have you tried adjusting [`matplotlib`'s artists](https://matplotlib.org/stable/tutorials/intermediate/artists.html)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Many matplotlib functions follow the [color cycler](https://matplotlib.org/stable/tutorials/intermediate/color_cycle.html) to assign default colors, but that doesn't seem to apply here.

The following approach loops through the generated annotation texts (`artists`) and the [clf tree structure](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/tree/plot_unveil_tree_structure.html#tree-structure) to assign colors depending on the majority class and the impurity (gini). Note that we can't use alpha, as a transparent background would show parts of arrows that are usually hidden.

```py
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.colors import ListedColormap, to_rgb
import numpy as np
from sklearn import tree

X = np.random.rand(50, 2) * np.r_[100, 50]
y = X[:, 0] - X[:, 1] > 20

clf = tree.DecisionTreeClassifier(random_state=2021)
clf = clf.fit(X, y)

fig, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(ncols=2, figsize=[21, 6])

colors = ['crimson', 'dodgerblue']
ax1.plot(X[:, 0][y == 0], X[:, 1][y == 0], "o", color=colors[0])
ax1.plot(X[:, 0][y == 1], X[:, 1][y == 1], "^", color=colors[1])
xx, yy = np.meshgrid(np.linspace(X[:, 0].min(), X[:, 0].max(), 100), np.linspace(X[:, 1].min(), X[:, 1].max(), 100))
pred = clf.predict(np.c_[(xx.ravel(), yy.ravel())])
ax1.contourf(xx, yy, pred.reshape(xx.shape), cmap=ListedColormap(colors), alpha=0.25)

# ax2.set_prop_cycle(mpl.cycler(color=colors)) # doesn't seem to work

artists = tree.plot_tree(clf, feature_names=["X", "y"], class_names=colors,
                         filled=True, rounded=True, ax=ax2)
for artist, impurity, value in zip(artists, clf.tree_.impurity, clf.tree_.value):
    # let the max value decide the color; whiten the color depending on impurity (gini)
    r, g, b = to_rgb(colors[np.argmax(value)])
    f = impurity * 2 # for N colors: f = impurity * N/(N-1) if N>1 else 0
    artist.get_bbox_patch().set_facecolor((f + (1-f)*r, f + (1-f)*g, f + (1-f)*b))
    artist.get_bbox_patch().set_edgecolor('black')

plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image: changing the colors of sklearn plot_tree]